# any real benefit of using servlet 3.1 async io?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, servlets, nio

I am wondering that if servlet containers like Tomcat, Jetty etc already use nio to read and write data back, is there really a need of using `setWritelistner` and `setReadListner` on servlet input and output streams? Is there any additional performance gain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The benefit is not directly<sup>1</sup> about "performance gain".  The purpose of those methods is to avoid a request thread (in async mode) from blocking when it reads input (POST) data or writes the document.

There is an example in the Java EE7 tutorial: ["17.13.1 Reading a Large HTTP POST Request Using Non-Blocking I/O"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets013.htm) (link updated).

This is orthogonal to Tomcat's use of nio under the covers.

---

<sup>1 - There is an indirect performance benefit.  When it is likely for threads to block on network I/O, an alternative strategy for increasing throughput is to increase the number of worker threads.  But that increases the memory footprint (among other things) resulting in more "overheads".</sup>

Comment: I am starting to read info about servlet 3.1, but is not clear for me how sending the job to a background executor and the servlet returning inmediatly freeing the container thread, is gaining something, the executor its a thread itselft, so resources will be consumed.

Comment: The benefits of async accrue if you can avoid blocking the request thread while waiting for something like request to a back-end service to complete.  Obviously, if you are doing the actual work in a background thread ... not some other machine ... you haven't achieved much.  I think you are thinking about the wrong use-case.

Comment: So, the real gain its when the job is made by another server? like in micro services? This is not for one server doing every thing? even this server is a multi tier application?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You also need to take into things like disk latency, and different application server performance properties.

Answer (score 8):

Tomcat reads the headers (and does so in a non-blocking mode for NIO) 
but reading request bodies is an application concern and is performed 
with blocking IO (till Servlet 3.0 requirement of the specification). Likewise, 
writing the response is done with blocking IO as that is also a 
requirement of the specification.

All of this changes with Servlet 3.1.

You may want to see [email Thread](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Getting-my-head-around-NIO-simulated-blocking-trying-to-td4996773.html) for this

Below para and code sample is from Java EE 7 Recipies it explains use of setWritelistner and setReadListner

> To implement a nonblocking I/O solution, new programming interfaces
>   have been added to ServletInputStream and ServletOutputStream, as well
>   as two event listeners: ReadListener and WriteListener. ReadListener
>   and WriteListener interfaces make the servlet I/O processing occur in
>   a nonblocking manner via callback methods that are invoked when
>   servlet content can be read or written without blocking. Use the
>   ServletInputStream.setReadList ener(ServletInputStream, AsyncContext)
>   method to register a ReadListener with a ServletInputStream, and use
>   the I/O read
>   ServletInputStream.**setWriteListener**(ServletOutputStream,AsyncContext)
>   method for registering a WriteListener. The following lines of code
>   demonstrate how to register a ReadListener implementation with a
>   ServletInputStream:

```
AsyncContext context = request.startAsync();
ServletInputStream input = request.getInputStream();
input.setReadListener(new ReadListenerImpl(input, context));
```

Answer (score 4):

Async IO can have a profound effect on performance in certain scenarios.  My experience is mostly with the ASP.NET equivalent, but it should apply here as well.

A servlet has a finite number of threads to handle requests.  If there is any sort of blocking IO (a network request, database query, etc) the thread handling the request remains in use while it sits around waiting for the IO to complete.  In high volume scenarios, this can starve the thread pool and cause serious performance degradation.

With async IO, IO does not block the request thread.  Instead, a callback is registered and subsequently called when the IO completes.  In the meantime, the thread is returned to the thread pool where it can continue to serve other requests.